# Invertibility of NxN nonnegative matrix with diagonally dominant elements

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-geometry

I have a NxN nonnegative matrix where the diagonal element of any row i is greater than the off diagonal elements, 1 > aii > aij ≥ 0 for j not equal to i . This not a diagonally dominant matrix as it is possible that aii < ∑aij over j not equal to i. I want to know if this matrix is generically invertible for arbitrary (random) coefficients maintaining the restriction, 1 > aii > aij ≥ 0. If the matrix is generically invertible a reference would be most helpful.

Comment: A Baire-generic matrix (without restriction on coefficients) is invertible, and your restriction consist in considering an open subset of all matrices. So sure the matrix you consider is generically invertible. I doubt you will find a reference as it is not specific to your particular restrictions at all.

Comment: As Benoit tells you; the intuition is as follows; for any such generic matrix, all elements are non-equal. Thus, we may fiddle each element a little bit and still satisfy all conditions you describe. Thus, there is an open ball around each generic matrix. If the generic matrix you started with was non-invertible, then some (most) elements in the small ball around this matrix must be invertible.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering if the argument fails with the addition restrictions aii = 1 - sii and sii = ∑aij over j not equal to i, where 0 < sii < 1 for all i = 1...N . If the argument fails, these restrictions satisfy a diagonally dominant matrix for sii < 5. I'm wonder if there is a further argument where these restrictions would give invertibiity for sii ≥ .5.